# Missing polygons and texture oddities with imported models (Cycles viewport/render 2.92)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I recently decided to try my hand at posing rigged models for fun, so I just grabbed some 3d models off of mihoyo's official downloads and imported it into blender using MMDTools, since that was what they were originally for. However, after setting everything up and converting all shaders for use with cycles, texture oddities occur in thin objects and polygons are missing not from the viewport cycles render, but the final render. The texture oddity in the viewport cycles render is acceptable, as most people won't notice that it is particularly different and it feels just like a pattern, but it gets worse in the final render, becoming more splotchy. Everything works fine in Eevee except for the hastily-made hairBSDF shader I applied to the hair since I couldn't find out how to modify the rest of the shaders on the model. As demonstrated below, there are missing polygons in the render once you press f12, specifically just in the hair. This is consistent no matter the shader I use, meaning that even if I took off my own hastily-made custom shader and used the auto-generated "toon" shader, it will still provide the same result. I am running cycles on CPU compute only, cpu is a Ryzen 9 3900x running at stock with a boxed cooler (will get something better at some point, opencl doesn't work properly with my GPU due to known issues with AMD gpus)
Images (top/bottom): Cycles final render at 1024 samples (no denoise), Eevee final render at 64 samples, Eevee viewport render at 16 samples, Cycles viewport render at 128 samples

[image: Cycles final render at 1024 sampels w/o denoise]
[image: Eevee final render at 64 samples]
[image: Eevee viewport render at 16 samples]
[image: cycles viewport render at 128 samples]

Comment: Hello and welcome. 2.93 Is still in alpha state, try to use a stable version

Comment: oh wait, it's actually blender 2.92 haha, I just misread my numbers, but yes I am running stable (my blender 3.0 exe hasn't been touched since installation)